# How to run a loop concurrently in Groovy?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, groovy

As of now I have code like following in groovy

```
    HashMap map = new HashMap()
    for(char i='a'; i<='z'; i++) {
      def name = getName(i)
      def info getInfo(i)
      map.put(name, info)
    }
    serializeMap(map)
```

What is the best way to run this loop concurrently in Groovy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a Groovy extension available called [GPars](http://www.gpars.org/). It supports several concurrency techniques like Fork/Join or the Actor model. Using GPars, your code could look like this (I couldn't figure out exactly what you are iterating over):

```
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

Map map = [:] as ConcurrentMap

GParsPool.withPool {
  chars.eachParallel { i ->
    def name = getName(i)
    def info = getInfo(i)
    map[name] << info
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use `foldParallel` as well to remove the requirement for the externally initialized `map`

Comment: @tim I think GPars has migrated to core Groovy in 1.8, is that right?

Comment: oops, the for loop was suppose to be 'a' to 'z' and not 'a' to 'a'. I am appending these characters to end of a URL to fetch and index the content of the webpages.

Comment: @Don it's distributed as a jar with groovy, but it's not part of the groovy-core, so you still need to add it to the classpath

Comment: @Grrrrr in this case you could write `("a".."z").eachParallel { i -> ` which uses a Groovy Range to go from a to z.

Comment: I added the jar to my project(class path) but i am getting Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.lang.ObjectRange.eachParallel() is applicable for argument types: (things.MayoExtract$_run_closure1) values: [things.MayoExtract$_run_closure1@3bc20e]. An idea?

Comment: Plz disregard the above comment, added the latest GParse.jar and fixed that issue but now I have Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jsr166y/ForkJoinPool

Comment: Ok... others who are trying to do this will need jsr166y and extra jsr166y jar files from http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/

Comment: Don't forget to make the map above thread-safe: Map map = [:] as ConcurrentMap to prevent the threads from racing over the shared map.

Answer (score 4):

Using Java streams:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "a1", "b1", "c1", "a2", "b2", "c2")
        .parallel()
        .forEach({ println it })
```